# Make desktop shortcut icon "always on top"?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, desktop

Is there a way to make desktop shortcut icons "always on top" — so that even when you open a window, the desktop shortcut icon stays on top of it?

Answer (score 0):

Well kind of a round about answer but in the bottom right, right of your task bar, is a rectangle button. This button will always be on top anyways and clicking it shows your desktop.  This has existed since Windows 7.

Comment: Funny that you mention that:  I just discovered that functionality yesterday.  That's not what I'm looking for though.  If possible, I just want the one shortcut icon to always be on top.

Comment: Not possible...